# Allow X-CSRF-TOKEN in laravel+vuejs project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors

I have created a laravel project with vuejs. I want to fetch the data.js file from the another server but not getting it. When I run the project following errors occurs in console

> Request header field X-CSRF-TOKEN is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I tried to resolved it but didn't get solution. Here is my code:

> cors.php

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{   
    //return $next($request);
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
    ];
    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        $response->header($key, $value);
    return $response;
}
```

> bootstrap.js

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
if (token) {
  window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
  console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x- 
  csrf-token');
}
```

I am getting X-CSRF-Token also in meta tag. How to allow this x-CSRF-token?. If anyone needs more information let me know. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably got something like this somewhere in your code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by adding this in your routes.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token,authorization');
```

I was facing the similar issue and adding this line in my routes file helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The **other server** does not accept the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in a CORS request.

There's not much you can do about that other than not sending the token in the request. In fact, sending the CSRF token to a remote server can compromise the safety of your users. Unless of course the other server is a server you control.

Just remove the lines that set the header in axios from your `bootstrap.js` to allow axios to do CORS requests but remember to always send the token.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');` by `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');`

```
let token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x- 
    csrf-token');
}
```